# Need help figuring out syntax error with audio

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have the following code:

```
var soundManager = {
    var _explode = new Audio('/Content/sounds/explosion.ogg');

    var _coin = new Audio('/Content/sounds/coin.ogg');
    this.play = function (name){
        switch(name){
            case "explosion":
                _explode.play();
                break;
            case "coin":
                _coin.play();
                break;
        }
    };
};
```

Chrome says I have an error on the second line, where _explode is defined.  What's the syntax error?  I'm trying to set it up so I can call soundManager.play(nameOfSound) to have it play an ogg file.

Thank you.

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write statements that way inside an object literal. Try the following -

```
var soundManager = {
    _explode: new Audio('/Content/sounds/explosion.ogg'),
    _coin: new Audio('/Content/sounds/coin.ogg'),

    play: function (name){
        switch(name){
            case "explosion":
                this._explode.play();
                break;
            case "coin":
                this._coin.play();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

To access this later, you can use something like the following -

```
soundManager.play('explosion');
soundManager.play('coint');
```

You can further improve your code by following @Passerby's suggestion -

```
var soundManager = (function () {
    var _explode = new Audio('/Content/sounds/explosion.ogg');
    var _coin = new Audio('/Content/sounds/coin.ogg');

    return {
        play: function (name) {
            switch (name) {
                case "explosion":
                    _explode.play();
                    break;
                case "coin":
                    _coin.play();
                    break;
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

Using [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) this way, only the `play` method will have access to the `_explode` and `_coin` variables.

Answer (score 2):

Just as @SayemAhmed said, your syntax to create an object literal is incorrect. And his answer is correct.

Here's my preferred way, to make `_explode` and `_coin` "true" private:

```js
var soundManager=(function(){
  var _explode=new Audio('/Content/sounds/explosion.ogg');
  var _coin=new Audio('/Content/sounds/coin.ogg');
  return {
    play:function(name){
      switch(name){
        case "explosion":
          _explode.play();
          break;
        case "coin":
          _coin.play();
          break;
      }
    }
  };
})();
```

Now not only does `_explode` and `_coin` become inaccessible, but you can also get a more "compressed" size when using JS minifiers like Google Closure Compiler, because all `_explode`  and `_coin` will be minimized.